# will io direction operation lock the file?

Tags: linux, redirect, io, truncate

i have a **growing** nginx log file about **20G** already, and i wish to rotate it.

1, i `mv` the old log file to a new log file

2, i do `> old_log_file.log` to truncate the old log file in about 2~3 seconds

if there's a lock(write lock?) on the old log file when i doing the truncating(about 2~3 seconds)?

at that 2~3s period, nginx returns 502 for waiting to append logs to old log file until lock released?

thank you for explaining.

Comment: `mv old_log_file.log new_log_file.log && touch old_log_file.log`

Comment: i don't think your comand would work, because `mv` does not change the `inode` of old log file. And `nginx` would still log into the "new_log_file"  because of the `inode`. And you create a new log file named as olg log file, but the `inode` changed, nginx wouldn't write into it until `nginx -s reload` the config file.

Comment: If that is how `nginx` associates the log, then you may well be correct. Then why not `cp -a old_log_file.log new_log_file.log && :> old_log_file.log`?

Comment: i tried 2 truncating methods: `>` and 'logrotate', they all caused the nginx output 502 -- very short period, after then 200.  and `logrotate`'s handling procedure is as you said truncate after `cp`.  now i have no idea what to debug this bug...

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a feature.

Comment: maybe i should dive into nginx to find out why a logging phase(nginx has 11 phases, logging is the last one.) would cause a server-end error code.   :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, there is (almost) no mandatory [file locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) (more precisely, there used to be some [mandatory locking feature](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) in the kernel, but it is deprecated and you really should avoid using it). File locking happens with [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) and is *advisory* and should be *explicit* (e.g. with [flock(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) command, or some program calling `flock` or `lockf`).

So every locking related to files is practically a *convention* between all the software using that file (and [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) or the redirection by your shell don't use file locking).

Remember that a file on Linux is mostly an [i-node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)) which could have zero, one or several file paths (see [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and be aware of [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html), [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)) and used thru some [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). Read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (and perhaps [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)) for more.

**No file locking happens in the scenario of your question** (and the i-nodes and file descriptors involved are independent).

Consider using [logrotate(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html).

Some software provide a way to reload their configuration and re-open log files.  You should read the documentation of your [nginx](http://nginx.org/).

Comment: `logrotate` 's source code shows that it first `cp` the old one then truncate the old one, `inode` doesn't change.  and actually i used `logrotate` after `>` causes 502 issue, but the issues still exist, then i asked this question.  sorry for my english.

Comment: `logrotate` and `kill -USR1 nginx.pid` which would reload the config file, all i tried does not solve the issue.

Comment: fine. i learned that "`>` " doesn't lock the file even though 2~3s' truncating at least.  thank you a lot, i would keep looking for answers for my 502.

Comment: Reason in terms of i-nodes and file descriptors. You'll understand better what happens in your computer

Comment: maybe, the file offset is decreasing quickly as `>` is truncating and at the same time nginx is appending logs with a shrinking offset (i don't know how to describe a unstable offset)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on application if it locks the file. Application that generates this log file must have option to clear log file. One example is in editor like vim file can be externally modified while it is still open in editor.